# finding the element in xml having namespace using the element path

Tags: java, xml

Currently i am having a xml as below.

```
<ns0:transaction>
    <ns0:node1> asdf</ns0:node1>
    <ns0:node2> asdf</ns0:node2>
    <ns0:node3> asdf</ns0:node3>
</ns0:transaction>
```

And i am having the path /transaction/node1 . But due to the namespace the java code which i am using is not able to fetch the data. Can you please suggest any alternative java code. I am not allowed to use the namespace in the path i am having.

Regards,

Comment: Why can't you use NS prefix in your XPath ? I suppose that you have control over the Java source code

Comment: we are have different sources sending different variable of the namespace, thats the reason we cannot use namespace

Comment: Do you know that the prefix is arbitrary and local to the document ? In fact local to the NS binding declaration. So the prefix in your XML documents can all be different and different from the prefix used in your XPath. It it not the prefix that counts, it is the NS name. You could do the mapping between prefix and NS name with an initialization step of the XPath engine in Java.

Comment: That being said, maybe the answer given is what you're looking for. If it is the case, do not forget to mark the answer as accepted by checking the V mark

Answer (score 1):

Try the xpath

```
/*[local-name()='transaction']/*[local-name()='node1']
```

The result of the local-name function is the element name without the namespace prefix